# Hudson rejects default view for "My Views," triggers NullPointerException

Tags: hudson

Our Hudson server now has about 70 jobs and I'd like to use 'My Views' to limit what I get on my dashboard.

I don't like the 'All' default view for "My Views" so I created a personal view and tried to set it in Hudson preferences for my account.

Whatever view name I put in, Hudson fails with a 500/NPE from Winstone.  Moreover, I can't get any default view back.

I updated Hudson to the latest version and it still fails.

Am I missing something simple?
Or are we misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to set your personal view as a global default view. (I'm not 100% sure about it, since I deal with Jenkins, not Hudson - things may be different). I do not think this can be done. I can propose two options:

- Create a global view that will contain the jobs everybody wants to see and set it as a global default view.
- Create your custom view and bookmark its URL.

Comment: Actually, no, I'm setting the default view in my personal settings page.  I set a default global view, it works fine.